# how to get the key or values one by one from the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

how to get the key or values one by one from the dictionary?

For example:

```
dictionary = {}
if x found in y:
    name = "simply"
    dictionary[name]={}
    bang = {'abc','dsw','lol'}
    dictionary[name]={bang}
for k in (dictionary):
    print (k)
```

what if i only want to get the first key `'abc'` ?

what method should i use since `print(k[0])` is not working for me.
it  will only print the 1st letter for all the keys

when i call `dictionary["simply"]`  it will show

```
abc

dsw

lol
```

What if I only wan to get `abc` for further steps?

Comment: By the way that is a `set` not `dict`.

Comment: `set`s are "**Unordered** collections of unique elements". You cannot be sure what will you get as the "first" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a set and not a dictionary. If you do dir with your set, you can see that there's no way to get a certain key by name from set. So you have to use a non in-built collection.

```
>>> dictionary={'abc','dsw','lol'}
>>> type(dictionary)
<type 'set'>
>>> dir(dictionary)
['__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iand__', '__init__', '__ior__', '__isub__', '__iter__', '__ixor__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__rand__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__ror__', '__rsub__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__xor__', 'add', 'clear', 'copy', 'difference', 'difference_update', 'discard', 'intersection', 'intersection_update', 'isdisjoint', 'issubset', 'issuperset', 'pop', 'remove', 'symmetric_difference', 'symmetric_difference_update', 'union', 'update']
>>> dictionary.pop()
'dsw'
>>>
```

You can install [ordered-set](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set) to do just that.

Do `pip install ordered-set` and then you can use it for your use case:

```
>>> from ordered_set import OrderedSet
>>> dir = OrderedSet(['abc','dsw','lol'])
>>> dir[0]
'abc'
```

Comment: So the result is not the "first" element.

Comment: pop removes an arbitrary element. OP Is asking for the first key, which is not possible to guarantee in a set.

Comment: It is not the first one 'abc' .. it ais still random

Comment: Check now. When you create a dictionary the elements are unordered. So you have to give a list to ordered set so that it can maintain the order.

Comment: Dictionary **is** a dict in OPs code.  bang is a set

Comment: OP updated the question; earlier it was a set. :(

Comment: thanks ! your answer help !

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are unordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, try OrderedDict.

```
>> from collections import OrderedDict
>> d = OrderedDict()    
>> d['apple'] = 'red'  
>> d['banana']='white'     
>> d.items()[0]

>> output: ('apple', 'red')
```

Comment: He has a set not a dictionary!

Comment: NameError: name 'collections' is not defined

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited the code, instead of writing collections.OrderedDict, simply write OrderedDict().

Comment: @wtpoo hey, your answer is correct, i can now do my jobs, thx, but why do u deleted it?

Comment: @Dsw Wds Cause you changed the question and my answer was no more relevant then